# HBase vs Cassandra - do hbase reads which do an extra lookup per key cause latency for random reads?

Tags: cassandra, hbase

For random key reads(not scans) Hbase would have to lookup the region in the master node which is an extra lookup per key, as I understand HBase client cannot infer the region looking at the key content directly, however Cassandra typically have the partitionID has part of the key through which it can infer the server directly, so is Hbase slower than Cassandra for random key lookups/reads?

Comment: there are so many factors that affect random read performance and this is just one of them.  so i don't think you can draw this conclusion.

Comment: The [row key range => HBase region] mapping is obtained from the Master at the first connection then it is cached on the client side. So there is no extra lookup.